# Form boundaries and writing php://input to a file in php

Tags: php, stream, put, boundary

So I want users to be able to upload big files without having to worry about the post max size values.
The alternative is using PUT and send a file as raw data.
When using jquery I can do this:

```
var data = new FormData();
  jQuery.each($('#file_upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
  data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php?filename=test.pdf',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'PUT',
});
```

In PHP I can do this:

```
$f = fopen($_GET['filename'], "w");
$s = fopen("php://input", "r");

while($kb = fread($s, 1024))
{ 
  fwrite($f, $kb, 1024); 
}
fclose($f);
fclose($s);
Header("HTTP/1.1 201 Created");
```

I am not doing:

```
$client_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Since putting the whole file into a variable will surely fill up all memory when uploading huge files.

The thing I cannot figure out is how to write the file data without the form boundaries.
Right now it writes at the top of the file something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVz0ZGHLGxBOCUVQG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-0"; filename="somename.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

and at the bottom something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVz0ZGHLGxBOCUVQG--
```

So I need to parse the data. But for that I need to read the whole data stream into memory and with large video files I don't want to do that.
I did read something about maybe creating a php://temp stream. But no luck yet with that.
How can I write just the content to a file, without the boundary header? And without first pumping all the data into a variable?

Comment: Could you provide the `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination of `fgets` to stop reading at a newline and checking for the boundaries:

```
while($kb = fgets($s, 1024))
{ 
    if(strpos($kb, '------') === false) //or !== 0 for first position
    {
        fwrite($f, $kb, 1024); 
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to be sure that '-----' is included into the same chunk? What if '---' is included in the end of first chunk and '---' - it's a start of the second one? Or it can not be the case?

Comment: `fgets` reads to the end of the line `\n`, so the - would be at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: If that is the case, what will happen with the following headers? They will damage the file as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) (there are many like it). It supports chunked uploads which means you won't hit any post/file max sizes as long as each upload chunk is less than the post max size.

It also includes the [PHP code](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php) you would need on the server side.

Comment: I use that blueimp uploader on a few sites that had lots of uploaded files and it worked well for my users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to recreate the wheel. Just use POST and change PHP's config to bigger limits. Those limits can also be set on a per directory / host basis.

Using .htaccess or your apache.conf

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
```

It is also a good idea to adjust other limits, like max_input_time.

Don't forget to relocated the received file using [move_uploaded_file](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fpt_BR%2Ffunction.move-uploaded-file.php&ei=93vaVPzBM5WTsQSF6YGYBQ&usg=AFQjCNGYdzHk2z7wP5A1dGiIL0cUwqRqFA&sig2=D930LEL6ubEskHE9l3VWxw&bvm=bv.85761416,d.cWc) to avoid any extra work.